# How Can I Execute DISM Through A Specific Source On Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, command-line, iso-image, dism

Right now I my computer crashes with errors like SystemService exception. It does this quite frequently. Especially if I run a GPU intensive application like a game.

I've executed a DISM command for RestoreHealth after sfc /scannow revealed corrupted files. However, it seems that the files needed for that are corrupted as well.

After going through a lot I decided to download a .iso file for my current build using Image Health and through that the Windows ISO Downloader from TechBench. I've made sure to check the System Info for the correct build.

Image Health wouldn't load the .iso file so I've tried doing it manually through admin command prompt. I've tried running DISM through the file both on the C drive as well as an external hard drive.

My last attempt used command `C:\WINDOWS\system32>Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:F:\Sources\Win10_1803_English_x64.iso` The F: drive is my external hard drive, Sources the folder Win10_1803_English_x64.iso is in.

Each time I get:

```
Error: 0x80004002

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.
```

Here is the log for my last DISM command attempt:

```
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Starting Dism.exe session ----->
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=10.0.17134, Running architecture=amd64, Number of processors=4
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Dism.exe version: 10.0.17134.1
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Executing command line: Dism  /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:F:\Sources\Win10_1803_English_x64.iso
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3452 TID=2576 Connecting to the provider located at C:\WINDOWS\system32\Dism\FolderProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=3452 TID=2576 physical location path: C:\ - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession
Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=3452 TID=2576 Event name for current DISM session is Global\{AD200B6F-15E9-489D-BF24-46581D2E741C} - CDISMManager::CheckSessionAndLock
Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=3452 TID=2576 Create session event 0x1ac for current DISM session and event name is Global\{AD200B6F-15E9-489D-BF24-46581D2E741C}  - CDISMManager::CheckSessionAndLock
Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=3452 TID=2576 Copying DISM from "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Dism" - CDISMManager::CreateImageSessionFromLocation
Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=3452 TID=2576 Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A" - CDISMManager::LoadRemoteImageSession
Info                  DISM   DISM Image Session: PID=6536 TID=8172 Instantiating the Provider Store. - CDISMImageSession::get_ProviderStore
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Initializing a provider store for the IMAGE session type. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\OSProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=6536 TID=8172 Defaulting SystemPath to C:\ - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect
Info                  DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=6536 TID=8172 Defaulting Windows folder to C:\Windows - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect
Info                  DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=6536 TID=8172 Host OS verion is 10.0 - CDISMOSServiceManager::SetDllSearchPath
Warning               DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=6536 TID=8172 Unable to set the DLL search path to the servicing stack folder. C:\Windows may not point to a valid Windows folder. - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Attempting to initialize the logger from the Image Session. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\LogProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger
Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Failed to load the provider: C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\PEProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider.  Continuing by assuming that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finished initializing the Provider Map. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=3452 TID=2576 Image session successfully loaded from the temporary location: C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Target image information: OS Version=10.0.17134.167, Image architecture=amd64
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session version: 10.0.17134.1
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Getting the collection of providers from an image provider store type. - CDISMProviderStore::GetProviderCollection
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\CbsProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  CSI    00000001 Shim considered [l:125]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\Servicing\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.165_none_eaf410441d6d7311\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND
Info                  CSI    00000002 Shim considered [l:122]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.165_none_eaf410441d6d7311\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_SUCCESS
Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finished initializing the CbsConUI Handler. - CCbsConUIHandler::Initialize
Info                  CSI    00000001 Shim considered [l:125]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\Servicing\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.165_none_eaf410441d6d7311\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND
Info                  CSI    00000002 Shim considered [l:122]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.165_none_eaf410441d6d7311\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_SUCCESS
Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 CBS is being initialized for online use. More information about CBS actions can be located at: %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log - CDISMPackageManager::Initialize
Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Loaded servicing stack for online use only. - CDISMPackageManager::CreateCbsSession
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\MsiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\IntlProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\IBSProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\DmiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
Info                  CSI    00000001 Shim considered [l:125]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\Servicing\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.165_none_eaf410441d6d7311\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND
Info                  CSI    00000002 Shim considered [l:122]'\??\C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.165_none_eaf410441d6d7311\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_SUCCESS
Info                  DISM   DISM Driver Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Further logs for driver related operations can be found in the target operating system at %WINDIR%\inf\setupapi.offline.log - CDriverManager::Initialize
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\UnattendProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\SmiProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Failed to load the provider: C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\EmbeddedProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\AppxProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\ProvProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\AssocProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\GenericProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\OfflineSetupProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\SysprepProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\TransmogProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=6536 TID=8172 Current image session is [ONLINE] - CTransmogManager::GetMode
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=6536 TID=8172 Audit Mode: [No] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=6536 TID=8172 GetProductType: ProductType = [WinNT] - CTransmogManager::GetProductType
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=6536 TID=8172 Product Type: [WinNT] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=6536 TID=8172 Product Type ServerNT : [No] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Connecting to the provider located at C:\Users\NATHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A\SetupPlatformProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Encountered a servicing provider, performing additional servicing initializations. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Got the collection of providers. Now enumerating them to build the command table.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Log Provider
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: OSServices
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Package Manager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DISM Package Manager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: MsiManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: MsiManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: IntlManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: IntlManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: IBSManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DriverManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DriverManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Unattend Manager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DISM Unattend Manager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: SmiManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: AppxManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: AppxManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: ProvManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: ProvManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: AssocManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: AssocManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: GenericManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: GenericManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: OfflineSetupManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: OfflineSetupManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: SysprepManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: SysprepManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: Edition Manager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: Edition Manager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: SetupPlatformManager
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: SetupPlatformManager.
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Processing the top level command token(cleanup-image). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2018-07-19 06:41:22, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2018-07-19 06:41:32, Warning               DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 CBS AddSource failed with HRESULT=0x80004002! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2018-07-19 06:41:32, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 CBS session options=0x40100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80004002)
Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x80004002)
Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x80004002)
Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80004002)
Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=80004002
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Found the PE Provider.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Package Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(MsiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: MsiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(IntlManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: IntlManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(IBSManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: IBSManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(DriverManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: DriverManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Unattend Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Unattend Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(SmiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: SmiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(AppxManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: AppxManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(ProvManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: ProvManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(AssocManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: AssocManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(GenericManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: GenericManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(OfflineSetupManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: OfflineSetupManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(SysprepManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: SysprepManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(Edition Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: Edition Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Finalizing the servicing provider(SetupPlatformManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: SetupPlatformManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Releasing the local reference to OSServices. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Disconnecting Provider: OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6536 TID=8172 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=3452 TID=2576 Closing session event handle 0x1ac - CDISMManager::CleanupImageSessionEntry
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3452 TID=2576 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3452 TID=2576 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3452 TID=2576 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

As I'm pretty inexperienced with reading logs I can't really tell if I have used incorrect syntax, which I doubt since the command at least was attempted. Perhaps I've used an incorrect file path or that it's failing to read the .iso file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Image session successfully loaded from the temporary location: C:\Users\XXXXXX~1\AppData\Local\Temp\E7EC0C8F-B546-44E5-8E7E-58BDD1A04B4A" - Indicates a image was successfully loaded.  You provided us the cbs.log, right?  "Target image information: OS Version=10.0.17134.167," - If your Source image and the Target image are not identical I wouldn't expect it to work.  If you don't attempt to specify an external image, and instead use the image already contained on your system, what does the log indicate?

Comment: It gets to about 85% before giving me Error: 0x800f0950

I can't post all the logs but here are a a couple of the warning ones:

    Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=8348 Failed to load the provider: C:\Windows\System32\Dism\SiloedPackageProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)

    Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=13040 TID=8348 Failed to load the provider: C:\Windows\System32\Dism\MetaDeployProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)

Comment: If I'm not giving the correct syntax and/or file path for the image then that's what I need help with. I've triple checked to make sure it's the correct build with my system.

If it's not even loading the .iso file then should I even attempt to use a .wim file?

Comment: I suppose I could upload the logs to Google Drive and Share it there. Would suggest I do that?

Comment: Or would you suggest I just reinstall Windows at this point. I probably would have had things up and running by now with my backups.

Comment: I've decided to just reinstall Windows at this point. I would say there's a 50/50 chance that I was doing something incorrectly or that something was broken that was preventing me from fixing it. Myself I would say it's more likely the latter.

Comment: Things are working just fine. Some of the SFC logs shows bad partitions so it's likely my hard drive may only have a few months left in it. In that case I'll be working towards getting a hard drive and replacing the one that's failing. Certainly wish someone had helped here but perhaps nobody else knew what was wrong either.